# Ckfinder azure set backend programmatically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config, ckfinder

I would like to set Azure as backend for CKFinder  and I want to read values (account, password) from AppSettings, not CKFinder setting for backend.
smthng like:

```
    <add key="CKFinderBackendAccountName" value="**********" />
    <add key="CKFinderBackendAccountKey" value="************" />
```

So far I have this code and I want only Azure account, password to be read from APPSettings. I see no corresponding property in ConnectorBuilder.

```
connectorBuilder.LoadConfig()
                .SetLicense(licenceDomain, licenceKey)
                .SetAuthenticator(customAuthenticator)
                .SetRequestConfiguration(
                    (request, config) =>
                    {                        
                        config.LoadConfig();
                        var defaultBackend = config.GetBackend("azureBackend");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep this is possible using **config.AddBackend()** and **config.AddResourceType()**

```
var connector = connectorBuilder
.LoadConfig()
.SetRequestConfiguration(
    (request, config) =>
    {
        config.LoadConfig();

        string accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CKFinderBackendAccountName"];            
        string accountKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CKFinderBackendAccountKey"];            

        // For saving images and files
        var azStorage = new AzureStorage(accountName, accountKey, "containername", "rootname");
        config.AddBackend("azstore", azStorage, baseUrl: "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/ckfinderstuff", isProxy: false);
        config.AddResourceType("Images", resourceBuilder => resourceBuilder.SetBackend("azstore", "images").SetAllowedExtensions("bmp", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"));
        config.AddResourceType("Files", resourceBuilder => resourceBuilder.SetBackend("azstore", "files").SetAllowedExtensions("7z", "aiff", "asf", "avi", "bmp", "csv", "doc", "docx", "fla", "flv", "gif", "gz", "gzip", "jpeg", "jpg", "mid", "mov", "mp3", "mp4", "mpc", "mpeg", "mpg", "ods", "odt", "pdf", "png", "ppt", "pptx", "pxd", "qt", "ram", "rar", "rm", "rmi", "rmvb", "rtf", "sdc", "sitd", "swf", "sxc", "sxw", "tar", "tgz", "tif", "tiff", "txt", "vsd", "wav", "wma", "wmv", "xls", "xlsx", "zip"));
    })
.SetAuthenticator(customAuthenticator)
.Build(connectorFactory);
```

You need to make sure you delete the `backend` and `resourceTypes` node under the `ckfinder` section in `web.config`

There isn't much documentation around this so I had to figure most of it out myself but you can see if the documentation here helps

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/configuration_by_code.html